# How to calculate all possible permutations of an assignment in Python?

Tags: python, permutation, variable-assignment

I am trying to calculate all possible ordered permutations of an assignment of n items to m entities (in Python), but I am stuck and would appreciate some help. In my case, all items are to be assigned, but it is not necessary for an entity to be assigned any items. By "ordered", I mean that the order matters so [0,1] is unique from [1,0].

In the case of three items and two entities, I am seeking to generate the following combinations (but I want to scale this up for larger m and n):

[[0,1,2],[]]

[[0,2,1],[]]

[[1,0,2],[]]

[[1,2,0],[]]

[[2,0,1],[]]

[[2,1,0],[]]

[[],[0,1,2]]

[[],[0,2,1]]

[[],[1,0,2]]

[[],[1,2,0]]

[[],[2,0,1]]

[[],[2,1,0]]

[[0,1],[2]]

[[1,0],[2]]

[[0,2],[1]]

[[2,0],[1]]

[[1,2],[0]]

[[2,1],[0]]

[[0],[1,2]]

[[0],[2,1]]

[[1],[0,2]]

[[1],[2,0]]

[[2],[0,1]]

[[2],[1,0]]

I have been trying to use Python's itertools.permutations, but I can't seem to think of anything that will scale up nicely. Can anyone suggest an algorithm or provide some guidance?

Comment: For n entities and m objects, the total assignments are (n+m-1)C(m-1). That might turn out to be a pretty large number

Comment: Yeah I won't scale up too far, but wanted to go slightly higher than 2/3.

Comment: Then what is your exact issue?

Comment: I don't know how to code it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible way:

```
from itertools import permutations, product, combinations_with_replacement

N_elems = 3
M_groups = 3

perm = permutations(range(N_elems))
bounds = combinations_with_replacement(range(N_elems+1), M_groups-1)
for p,b in product(perm, bounds):
    b = (0,)+b+(N_elems+1,)
    L = [p[b[i]:b[i+1]] for i in range(M_groups)]
    print(L)
```

Explanation:

- `perm = permutations(range(N_elems))` gets you all possible orderings
- `bounds = combinations_with_replacement(range(N_elems+1), M_groups-1)` gets you all possible ways to split this ordering into M groups
- `product(perm, bounds)` gets you all possible orderings and splits leading to a different possible 'assignment'

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was after. It is much appreciated!